# Drawing a Pattern with Nested Loops using PHP

Tags: php, for-loop, while-loop

I am trying to create an upside down half pyramid. The pyramid needs to have a random number between 1 and 20. There will be a refresh button at the top of the pyramid and when that is clicked it will generate a new rand(1,20) pyramid pattern. It would look like this

```
****
 ***
  **
   *
```

I don't know if I am doing the code correctly for the PHP. Some guidance would be great.

PHP code is below

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Drawing a Pattern with Nested Loops</h2>
        <input type="submit" value="Refresh" onclick=""window.location.reload()"/>
        <?php

            $star = rand(1,20);
            $row = 1;
            $col =1;

               while($row <= $star) {
                   for($col = 1; $col < $row; $col++)
                   {
                       echo " * ";
                   }
                   echo "<br>";
                   $col--;
               }
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The succinct way of doing this would be

```
$star = rand(1,20);
while($star) {
   echo str_repeat('*', $star) . '<br>';
   $star --;
}
```

But if you need to use a nested loop you can replace the `str_repeat` with a loop like the following

```
$star = rand(1,20);
while($star) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $star; $i++) {
        echo '*';
    }
    echo '<br>';
    $star --;
}
```

Although a `foreach` would be cleaner in my opinion

```
$star = rand(1,20);
while($star) {
    foreach(range(1,$star) as $index) {
        echo '*';
    }
    echo '<br>';
    $star --;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining that to me. That makes it easier to understand. @joelrosenthal